# Why can't variables be set to named characters

Tags: symbols, named-characters

Why can't variables be `Set` to [named characters](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListingOfNamedCharacters.html) as shortcuts? eg

`a = \[UpArrow]`

Gives syntax error:

> `"e=\[UpArrow]" is incomplete; more input is needed.`

Comment: It's [defined as an operator,](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorsWithoutBuiltInMeanings.html), so you can only define it as an operator like `a_\[UpArrow]b_ := 3 a + 4 b`

Comment: Not sure why you need this. Can you provide more context? To automate this, you could conceivably do something like `a = ToBoxes[x\[UpArrow]y][[1, 2]]`, which would give you the uparrow as a *string* (i.e. "\[UpArrow]").

Comment: You **can** set a variable equal to this character, via `a = UpArrow`, but it can still really only be used as an operator:  `a[3,4]` gives output like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IeulT.png)

Comment: @JasonB, I'd just like to use 1 or 2 letters as shortcuts versus typing backslash etc. Are all the named characters defined as operators?

Comment: @alancalvitti Of course not! Just think of all the Greek letters...

Comment: @sebhofer, that's what I thought, and I see now that it's possible to set variables to the latter, eg `a = \[Alpha]`. So which of the named variables are operators and which are not?

Comment: Related: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Operators.html

Comment: [Letters and Letter‐like Forms](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html)

Comment: @Karsten7, didn't know about that page.